# Add "Application Menu" to dock?

Tags: unity, menu, dock

I currently have a love/hate thing going on with Ubuntu - I like the fact is has a strong userbase, good support and looks polished, but am frustrated by a handful of user interface issues I wish I could change...

I would like the option of having an "Application Menu" available in the dock. Similar to other distributions (or the Windows start menu) which show all the applications currently installed with a single click. I know you can find this information using the Dock. But I would like a button specifically to do this which could be added, for example, right underneath the Dock button.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the ubuntu symbol and selecting "Applications"?

Comment: He wants something accessible by one click, and that shows all the applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed classicmenu-indicator and like it quite a bit for this purpose.  I still use Unity and HUD almost exclusively but in testing this certainly fits the bill.
http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/classicmenu-indicator/

I went the PPA route

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diesch/testing    
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator
```

Comment: Thanks, I think Classic Menu Indicator is the closest to what I was looking for. 

I can only assume that the dock itself is not configurable to be able to create custom items (other than simple shortcuts) otherwise I'm guessing someone would have done this.